# Store image on server with html/javascript/mongodb

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, mongodb, upload

I want to upload an image from a user to the server. With the all path, it works (I can store on MongoDB). But with `<input id ='image_upload' type='file' name='image_upload' />`, it doesn't works (security, no full path)

So I want to know if there is an other way to do that. Maybe asolution where I store directly on the server will be ok (Using javascript, html, ajax, ... )

Thank you

Comment: do you understand my solution, and how you can use ajax to send an image from a form ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use form data as such:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Paticularly,

```
var formData = new FormData();
// HTML file input, chosen by user
formData.append("userfile", fileInputElement.files[0]);
```